# Copy row by row of one sheet of a workbook into another sheet of another workbook

Tags: c#

Copy row by row of one sheet of a workbook into another sheet of another workbook.

```
public static void Main()
{
    CopyExcelData();
}

public static void CopyExcelData()
{
    Excel.Application excelapp = new Excel.Application();
    excelapp.Workbooks.Add();
    string path = @"E:\test\hello.xlsx";
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(path);
    Excel.Worksheet workSheet = workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(i);
    workSheet.Range["A2:B2"].Copy(workSheet.Range["A3:B3"]);
    workSheet.Range["A3:B3"].Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
    var source = workSheet.Range["A2:B2"].Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
    Excel.Range dest = workSheet.Range["A3:B3"];
    workSheet.Range["A2:B2"].Copy(dest);
    excelapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\my\\Desktop\\test " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") + ".xlsx");
    //excelapp.Visible = false;
    excelapp.ActiveWorkbook.Close();
}
```

I have used the below code but in this I have to specify cells hardcoded, I want to do it dynamically.

Comment: Dynamically as in, find out what cells have data and copy that data?